# Symfony2 Logging out from ssl subdomain

Tags: php, symfony, ssl

I'm forced to use a subdomain for ssl connections.

My Idea of solving the log-in / log-out process is to use the routing-configuration to "redirect" on the ssl-subdomain and to use https. The log-out process should do the opposite: "redirect" to the original domain an use http.
Everything works except that the user is still logged in after the log-out process.

My routing.yml looks like:

```
userarea:
    resource: "@BlueChordUserBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    schemes:  [https]
    host:     example.hosted-secure.com
    prefix:   /

adminarea:
    resource: "@BlueChordAdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    schemes:  [https]
    host:     example.hosted-secure.com
    prefix:   /

website:
    resource: "@BlueChordWebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

login_check:
    path:   /{_lang}/dashboard/login_check
    schemes:  [https]
    host:     example.hosted-secure.com

logout:
    path:   /{_lang}/dashboard/logout
    schemes:  [http]
    host:     example.com

loginfailure:
    path:   /{_lang}/login
    schemes:  [https]
    host:     example.hosted-secure.com
```

I've find more or less similar questions here but non of them was helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could not work due to cookie domain restriction. Your session cookie is saved for domain hosted-secure.com in client browser. If you redirect user to logout action on example.com, client browser won't send session cookie to server. example.com simply does not see session cookie.

How about having logout action under ssl subdomain and redirect to original http domain after successful logout?

Comment: Ok thats a good point! Would you use a logout-listener to achieve it?

Comment: Try to set logout action under https and host to example.hosted-secure.com in routing.yml. Now you should be able to logout user. Then set the logout target key as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out) in security.yml. Especially look at the tip. You can write your own success_handler and do what you exactly want after logout. But target key should be good enough for simple redirect. I think it accepts even route name. I hope everything will be smooth.

Comment: Yeah Perfect!!! I didn't check out the target for the last days! Good you where reminding me to it! Thanks!